# Convert prompt-sync require into import method

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, input, prompt

I use [`prompt-sync`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prompt-sync)  module in my Node project.

```
 const prompt = require('prompt-sync')();
 const result = prompt(message);
```

But to keep my TypeScript code consistent I need to use `import` instead of  `require`.
So I installed types for the package.

```
npm i @types/prompt-sync
```

And I tried to use it like

```
import * as promptSync from 'prompt-sync';
...
const prompt = promptSync();
const result = prompt(message);
```

But the error appeared

```
Error:(24, 20) TS2349: This expression is not callable.
Type '{ default: (config?: Config | undefined) => Prompt; }' has no call signatures.
```

So how can I use prompt-sync with `import`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error is raised because you cannot call a namespace import (`* as ns`). This restriction is per the ECMAScript specification which mandates that module namespace objects, such as the aforementioned syntax creates, cannot have a `[[Call]]` or `[[Construct]]` signature.

This results in a mismatch when attempting to consume CommonJS modules from ES modules as many of the former export a single function or constructor *as* the module itself (i.e. `module.exports = function () {}`).

However, there is interop capability specified and conventionalized which works by synthesizing  a `default` export for the CommonJS module that contains the value of `module.exports`.

You can and should leverage this interop facility.

Firstly, ensure that [`"esModuleInterop"`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#esModuleInterop) is specified with a value of `true` in your `tsconfig.json` under `"compilerOptions"`.

Secondly, rewrite your code to import the synthetic default from the `prompt-sync` module

```
import promptSync from 'prompt-sync';

const prompt = promptSync();

const result = prompt(message);
```

Answer (score -2):

i have done following steps and it work for me

1. npm i prompt-sync
2. npm i --save-dev @types/prompt-sync
3. npm i --save-dev @types/node
4. use following code in my program

   ```
   import PromptSync = require("prompt-sync");
   var prompt = require('prompt-sync')();
   let x = prompt("How old are you?");
   ```

and it works for me

Comment: This isn't improper code but it doesn't answer the question which seeks to use ES Module syntax.