# What's the correct way to import default export from JS file into TS file

Tags: typescript

I have a JS file that defines a function like this in `plugin.js`:

```
function getCompareSnapshotsPlugin(on, config) { ...}

module.exports = getCompareSnapshotsPlugin;
```

The declaration file `plugin.d.ts` is defined like this:

```
declare function getCompareSnapshotsPlugin(
  on: Cypress.PluginEvents,
  config: Cypress.PluginConfigOptions,
): void;

export default getCompareSnapshotsPlugin;
```

**I'm trying to import the function into my TS file. What's the correct way to do and why?**

Regular way like this

```
import getCompareSnapshotsPlugin from 'cypress-visual-regression/dist/plugin';
```

gives no TS error at compile time, but at runtime `getCompareSnapshotsPlugin`  is `undefined`.

[Here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5565#issuecomment-154886345) they suggest to `to write it as a namespace import (as opposed to a default import)` like this:

```
import * as getCompareSnapshotsPlugin from 'cypress-visual-regression/dist/plugin';
```

This **works** at runtime

```
getCompareSnapshotsPlugin(on, config);
```

but gives TS error during compile time (that I can workaround with ts-ignore):

> This expression is not callable. Type 'typeof
> import('cypress-visual-regression/dist/plugin')' has no call
> signatures.

Comment: This advice in  https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5565#issuecomment-154886345 has impeccable provenance but it's out of date. In order to answer your question, tell us if the plug-in and its typing is something that you maintain or if it's an external library

Comment: @AluanHaddad it's [an external library](https://github.com/mjhea0/cypress-visual-regression), but I think we can suggest an improvement for them if needed

Comment: I don't think you need to actually change it, because you can configure your compiler to handle it but the Declaration in the source file or not in complete agreement

Comment: The proper, standards compliant, and interoperable to write this code is as follows: `import getCompareSnapshotsPlugin from 'cypress-visual-regression/dist/plugin';` in order to make this work you need to inform typescript by setting `esModuleInterop: true`

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help. I wrote an answer here which explains the phenomenon in detail. Let me know if that satisfies your desire for knowledge.https://stackoverflow.com/a/65852551/1915893

Comment: The plugin module file uses commonjs format to provide its export. We know that because it assigns to `module.exports`. Leveraging the `esModuleInterop` the language wraps references to the import in an adapter. Very roughly the adapter looks like `const interopRequireDefault = m => "__esModule" in m ? m : {default: m, ...m.exports}`. Note that I've simplified several tangential details

Comment: @AluanHaddad, got it, thanks! I removed my comment after I read yours. So is this `esModuleInterop`configuration option is related to Cjs modules that export defaults like this `module.exports=getCompareSnapshotsPlugin` ?

Comment: No because `module.exports = value` isn't a default export at all. This might seem like a pedantic difference but it's actually quite significant and it's a primary source of the incompatibility and what necessitates an adapter. In ESM default isn't special like export assignment is. Rather, default in ESM is just another named export, an export named default, with special syntax provided for convenient import (`import a from "a"` is precisely equivalent to `import {default as a} from "a"`). This complexity is exacerbated by history

Comment: I hope that's relatively clear. I haven't slept a lot recently.

Comment: @AluanHaddad, yes, appreciate your explanations!

Comment: I forgot to mention, the problem with the Declaration file is that it should use `export = getCompareSnapshotsPlugin`. In other words, it should match the JavaScript source file and not use  `export default`

Comment: @AluanHaddad, I see, so would I still then need `esModuleInterop`?

Comment: Yes you would still need it. The Declaration files, and type information generally, do not influence module system interoperability. The reason to fix the Declaration file is to improve type checking. The current version allows importing as if the source code provided a `default`, producing no TS error even when the `esModuleInterop` is not enabled. Furthermore, it prevents scenarios that to consume the commonjs directly via `require` from type checking

Comment: @AluanHaddad, awesome, thanks for taking the time to explain this stuff! Appreciate